# Most efficient way to show a selection as main box

Tags: javascript, html, css, selection

I'd like to have a few options to choose from and show the selection as the main content. Similar to a picture lightbox etc but the thumbnails and main picture are html/content. I'd click a HTML box/div and it populates the larger/main box as the selection. I Could have used `options <select>` but images don’t work as options.
[selection box image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqV43.jpg)

If you know of any efficient ways to do this via HTML, CSS or Javascript please let me know.

I've found this code here http://jsfiddle.net/EhtrR/1238/ but worried if it will be too much Javascript assuming I may have 20+ options on the page:

```
$("#img1").on('click', function() {
   $("#div1").show();
   $("#div2,#div3,#div4").hide();
});
$("#img2").on('click', function() {
   $("#div2").show();
   $("#div1,#div3,#div4").hide();
});
$("#img3").on('click', function() {
   $("#div3").show();
   $("#div1,#div2,#div4").hide();
});
$("#img4").on('click', function() {
   $("#div4").show();
   $("#div1,#div2,#div3").hide();
});
```

Could this be minified?

Comment: Usually you just use two colours, for selected and unselected.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like that

html :- any chosen image will appear in the empty div

```
<div class="SImgs">
    <img src="./imgs/652.jpg" onclick="getSrc(this.src)" alt="img">
    <img src="./imgs/3833.jpg" onclick="getSrc(this.src)" alt="img">
    <img src="./imgs/6617.jpg" onclick="getSrc(this.src)" alt="img">
    <img src="./imgs/4213114.jpg" onclick="getSrc(this.src)" alt="img">

</div>
 <div class="mainImg">

    </div>
```

javaScript :-

```
    function getSrc(clicked_src) {
        const d = document.querySelector('.mainImg');
        d.innerHTML = "<img src=\'" + clicked_src + "\'>"
    }
```

css:- then you can style it as you like

```
    .SImgs {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    
    .SImgs img {
        width: 7rem;
        height: 5rem;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .mainImg {
        width: 25rem;
        height: 20rem;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    
    .mainImg img {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

Comment: That is perfectly clean although instead of images I need DIV/html boxes if that makes sense. I'm thinking along the lines of getID of clicked and change from display:none > block to populate the inner html of the main box with the html that is selected?

Comment: do you mean that you have an div contains images and paragraphs and when you click on it all the contents appear in a bigger div .                                                                             or you have a div with background image and when you click on it the image appears in anther div